# Linking external object files on the fly in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, ghci

My project uses FFI, so I always have to link against precompiled object files testing with GHCi:

```
ghci Foo a.o
```

My question is: Is there a way to do this *once GHCi is running* instead of GHCi startup?
I've tried this:

```
$ ghci
> :l Foo a.o
```

but I get the error `a.o is not a module name or a source file`

My goal for this is to be able to *start* a GHCi session with external symbols linked in via a `.ghci` file. My motivation is that cabal compiles the object files into `dist/build/my-tests/my-tests-tmp/src/../../../../a.o`, which ends up being 92 characters long. It's bad enough to have to type this once (with a `*,o` at the end), but due to a [regression in GHC 7.8](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9074), I have to link five object files in a specific order which requires over 500 characters after `ghci Foo`.

** UPDATE **

The following example demonstrates why n.m.'s solution below isn't working for me on GHC 7.8.2:

mul.c

```
#include <inttypes.h>
void mulRq (int64_t* a, int64_t* b, int32_t totm, int64_t q) { }
```

Mul.hs

```
module Mul where

import Data.Int
import Foreign.Ptr

foreign import ccall unsafe "mulRq" mulRq :: 
  Ptr Int64 -> Ptr Int64 -> Int64 -> Int64 -> IO ()
```

Dummy.hs is empty.

Steps:

1. ghci Mul

   [can't find label mulRq]
2. gcc -c -o mul.o mul.c
3. ghci Mul mul.o

   [ghci loads]
4. ghci -fobject-code Dummy
5. ghci Dummy

   [ghci loads *without* compiling]
6. ld -r Dummy.o mul.o -o temp.o
7. mv temp.o Dummy.o
8. ghci Dummy

   [ghci loads *without* compiling]
9. nm Dummy.o

   [verify that Dummy.o contains the symbol mulRq]

Now start ghci:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.2: 
...
Prelude> :l Dummy
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
Prelude Main> :l Mul
[1 of 1] Compiling Mul              ( Mul.hs, interpreted )

ByteCodeLink: can't find label
During interactive linking, GHCi couldn't find the following symbol:
  mulRq
```

Comment: Use a shell script instead of a `.ghci`?

Comment: Can you wrap the objects in dummy Haskell/ghc modules?

Comment: You can also have a `.ghci` file on a [per-project basis](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html) that you can set up to load the object files you need just for that project.  It'll load them all when you start GHCi, but at least you can control it more for whatever project you're working on and don't have to have them global.

Comment: @n.m. Sounds interesting...how would I do that?

Comment: @bheklilr I do have a per-project .ghci file. That's exactly what I'm asking: how do I set it up to load the object files at the start of GHCi?

Comment: @minitech I know I *could*, but I'd rather use built-in GHCi capabilities (if it exists) before hacking my way around the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Compile a Haskell module `Dummy.hs` into `Dummy.o`. It can be totally empty, or contain any useful Haskell code.
2. Make sure `ghci Dummy` loads an existing compiled version of `Dummy` (does not print `Compiling` when loading it).
3. Combine `Dummy.o` and `a.o`:

   ld -r Dummy.o a.o -o temp.o
   mv temp.o Dummy.o
4. Now you have a loadable Haskell module `Dummy` that also contains all of the `a.o`.

**Update**

This scheme works if modules that *use* `a.o/Dummy.o` are compiled to object code, and does not work if they are interpreted.

A simple way to always use compiled code is to run GHCi with `-fobject-code`. Using your example,

```
ghci -fobject-code
Prelude> :l Dummy
Ok, modules loaded: Dummy.
Prelude Dummy> :l Mul
[1 of 1] Compiling Mul              ( Mul.hs, Mul.o )
Ok, modules loaded: Mul.
Prelude Mul>
```

Comment: This would work okay, until the original `a.o` changes and I forget to rebuild `Dummy.o`. But it's better than what I've got right now.

Comment: How do I make ghci not recompile Dummy.hs? I compile Dummy.hs first using `ghc Dummy`, then `ghci Dummy`, but ghci still compiles Dummy again.

Comment: Run `ghci -fobject-code Dummy` once to compile Dummy. See [this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025006/ghci-never-loads-compiled-files) of mine.

Comment: That make GHCi print "Compiling" once instead of twice, not sure if that's enough. However, this involves me calling GHCi with args. I'm trying to put a `:l Dummy` in my .ghci file, which doesn't allow for those args, at least that I can tell.

Comment: Ghci ought to be able to use modules compiled with ghc. It currently isn't. I suspect it's a ghc bug. Using ghci -fobject-code is a workaround. Just use it instead of ghc for this module until there is a real solution.

Comment: To reiterate, you only need to run `ghci -fobject-code Dummy` once. It will produce .o and .hi files, just like ghc -c would.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you want me to do with `ghci -foject-code`. When I do that, ghci doesn't recompile the file. `ghci Foo -fobject-code` runs without exception, but when I try to load `ghci Foo` using the compiled object file, ghci doesn't compile Foo, but it does print `target '-f-object-code is not a module name or source file`, and it doesn't seem to be loading my extra object files after including them in `Foo.o`. I'm filing this as a bug.

Comment: Please see [this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025006/ghci-never-loads-compiled-files) again, there is an answer there.

Comment: Okay, I got ghci to load the file without recompilation and/or errors. However, after loading the compiled module "Foo" (I verified that Foo.o contains the symbols I need), running `:l MyModule`, where `MyModule` needs the symbols in the .o file, claims it can't find the symbols. So it seems the symbols aren't available in GHCi.

Comment: Of course, if I *start* GHCi using `ghci MyModule Linker.o`, it finds all of the symbols, but I'm trying to avoid having to add an explicit argument when invoking GHCi...

Comment: Before answering I have specifically tested for this case and verified it does work. If you don't mind posting your non working test case on github or some such I will try to check it.

Comment: I've updated the question with a detailed minimal example of why this solution isn't working for me. I really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Any idea what we are doing differently?

Comment: See update. The difference is that I have used -fobject-code everywhere, including the final stage of loading Mul.

Comment: I tried it step by step just as explained by you. Unfortunately, it works only half way for me. I defined my own function in C and imported via Foreign into my haskell module. the compiling works and once loaded into ghc it will find the defined function BUT: If I try to use the function ghci will complain about symbol not found.