# GHCi never loads compiled files

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Write a module:

```
module Foo where
foo = 3.14
```

Compile it:

```
ghc -c Foo.hs
```

Load it:

```
ghci -ignore-dot-ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :l Foo
[1 of 1] Compiling Foo              ( Foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Foo.
```

Why won't GHCi pick up compiled code? Is it a bug in GHCi?

I tried to run with `-v`, not too helpful.

**Update**

I have found that If the module is compiled with `GHCi -fobject-code Foo`, GHCi will subsequently load the compiled version, even without `-fobject-code`.

**Update 2**

This all happens with Ghc 7.8 on a Linux machine. Ghc 7.6 on a Windows machine does not exhibit this problem.

Comment: I don't know your backgrounds here - but if you have a (somewhat current) cabal setup then just go with `cabal repl` this don't recompile for me and it uses sandboxes (if any) correctly

Comment: I just was your update - I have to admit I only tested this on 7.6.3 so maybe it's an 7.8.x issue - I can only tell you with the next plattform (don't like to mess to much with my env ;) )

Comment: Does `7.6` work with or without `-fobject-code` ?

Comment: @Sibi 7.6 works without, just like the user guide describes.

Comment: @n.m. Ah, okay. It works for me too without `-fobject-code`. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [GHC 7.8.1 Release Notes](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1/html/users_guide/release-7-8-1.html)

> On Linux, FreeBSD and Mac OS X, GHCi now uses the system dynamic
>   linker by default, instead of its built in (static) object linker.
>   This is more robust cross-platform, and fixes many long-standing bugs
>   (for example: constructors and destructors, weak symbols, etc work
>   correctly, and several edge cases in the RTS are fixed.)
>
> As a result of this, GHCi (and Template Haskell) must now load dynamic
>   object files, not static ones. To assist this, there is a new
>   compilation flag, -dynamic-too, which when used during compilation
>   causes GHC to emit both static and dynamic object files at the same
>   time. GHC itself still defaults to static linking.
>   [...]
>
> Currently, Dynamic GHCi and -dynamic-too are not supported on Windows (32bit or 64bit.)

The last sentence explains why this doesn't affect windows.

You can see the problem by comparing the files that `ghci -fobject-code Foo` and `ghc Foo` generates:

```
$ mkdir ghci ghc
$ ghc Foo -odir ghc -hidir ghc
$ ghci -fobject-code Foo -odir ghci -hidir ghci < /dev/null
$ diff -u <(ghc --show-iface ghc/Foo.hi) <(ghc --show-iface ghci/Foo.hi)
--- /proc/self/fd/11    2014-07-30 13:03:34.977845398 +0200
+++ /proc/self/fd/12    2014-07-30 13:03:34.978845419 +0200
@@ -3,13 +3,13 @@
 Version: Wanted [7, 0, 8, 3],
          got    [7, 0, 8, 3]
 Way: Wanted [],
-     got    []
+     got    [d, y, n]
 interface main:Foo 7083
   interface hash: 9aab457c4ecbd2507529fcb479523944
   ABI hash: 375e3124c60d5f4eb51e7e38e71a3be0
   export-list hash: ff40b932e3d14f0fc26fbd56a58e227c
   orphan hash: 693e9af84d3dfcc71e640e005bdc5e2e
-  flag hash: 6c2d0082779adc2bd558d879f3f0fe26
+  flag hash: 82fa613fe97939e6767d853897fe1074
   used TH splices: False
   where
 exports:
```

This shows that GHCi compiles haskell files to *dynamic* object files (`dyn` way), while
GHC compiles to *static* object files.

When GHCi tries to load Foo, it notices that there is no dynamic object file for Foo available (because GHC generated a static one), and thus it recompiles Foo. If `-fobject-code` is given, this will now override the static object file and generate a dynamic one,
so that no recompilation is needed the next time GHCi is started. If `-fobject-code` is not
specified, no object code is generated and the file is loaded in interpreted mode.

You can also tell `ghc` to generate dynamic object files:

```
$ ghc -dynamic -c Foo
```

Now `ghci Foo` doesn't recompile Foo, but uses the already-compiled dynamic object file.